Selenium Browser not loading all the dynamic data
I am trying to scrape a single datapoint from the following website
The datapoint is the value of the service charge in the property information table.
If i navigate to the website myself I can see the field, see the image.

However, if I use selenium with python, the field does not populate, even after waiting for everything to load. So my code returns an error saying it cannot find the element.

I cannot understand why its not loading. I know its dynamic content, but there is other dynamic content that does load. I have tried vpn, different browsers, wait times, but nothing has worked. So I am posting here for help.
I know that I cant figure it out because I don't fully understand how web browsers and selenium work. So any education will be highly appreciated.
Here is my code. It's got a bunch of extra stuff because it's my code I use to trouble shoot.
import sys
sys.path.append('/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages')
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from IPython.display import clear_output
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from datetime import datetime as dt
import time
import undetected_chromedriver as uc


listingurl = "https://www.bayut.com/property/details-10040631.html"

#headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36'}
my_user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36"

# Set up Chrome options
chrome_options = Options()

# Create a new instance of ChromeDriver with the desired options
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

# Set the custom User-Agent
chrome_options.add_argument(f"--user-agent={my_user_agent}")
driver = webdriver.Chrome()


driver.get(listingurl)
# Get user Agent with execute_script
driver_ua = driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent")
print("User agent:")
print(driver_ua)
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.execute_script('return document.readyState') == 'complete')
servcharge = driver.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value='[aria-label="Service charges"]')
print(servcharge)

Appreciate all the help!

with "human" browsing: some requests are hanging and i can't see the field most of the time. the data is protected by cloudfront, so maybe there's no solution

Thanks for commenting Folen. If you browsed the website, not all listing have this data available because some building might be new. So it is possible some pages won’t display it even with “human” browsing. How can you tell it is protected by cloud front and what does that mean?

oh i'm an idiot, sorry. i mixed cloudflare and cloudfront. cloudflare is the one for data protection and can efficiently block bots, cloudfront is just a hosting service. but anyway it lags. with the link you provided, where we know the field is populated, it fails to be displayed very often (average rent is empty, and no service charges).

When you say it fails to be displayed very often, do you mean during human browsing? And what counts as very often. I’ve never had it not populate while human browsing.
